# Django settings.DATABASE error

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-database

**EDIT**
I'm receiving this error when migrating:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

My DATABASE config for settings.py is like so:

```
DATABASES = { 
  'default': {},
  'db1': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'metrix1',
    'USER': 'appserver',
    'PASSWORD': '***',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '2323',
  },  
  'db2': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'metrix2',
    'USER': 'appserver',
    'PASSWORD': '***',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '2324',
  },  
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks.

**EDIT**
**THIS PART FIXED**
there was a typo with the user credentials.

Also getting this error--not sure if it's related to the settings.DATABASES error I'm receiving:

```
OperationalError at /counters_app/
(1045, "Access denied for user 'appserver'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/counters_app/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(1045, "Access denied for user 'appserver'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in __init__, line 204
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:
```

Comment: That does not explain the error. Is there addional code that says which DB Ro use? Maybe using an environmental variable?

Comment: What are you attempting to run and how?

Comment: @alexanderlukanin13 I'm attempting to run a basic counters Django app on aws instance and trying to access its index page locally.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry, could you clarify your question? I thought that the error was coming from improper database setting in settings.py

Comment: Your second error shows your user doesn't have permissions on your db (or wrong credentials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** configure `'default'` database, according to [settings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases).

Comment: omg no you were completely right! I thought I could leave it empty, but I guess I needed to configure it!! thank you!

Comment: I do believe that alexanderlukanin13 is probably right, certainly the settings docs say that, but take a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/), the second code snippet down from the top. I tried that, but I'm getting the error.